# Running a shell script from Python which requires user input

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a shell command which needs some user confirmation from stdin like below

```
support@vrni-platform:/tmp$ patronictl -c /etc/patroni/patroni.yml remove arkin
+---------+--------+------+------+-------+-----------+
| Cluster | Member | Host | Role | State | Lag in MB |
+---------+--------+------+------+-------+-----------+
+---------+--------+------+------+-------+-----------+
Please confirm the cluster name to remove: arkin
You are about to remove all information in DCS for arkin, please type: "Yes I am aware": Yes I am aware
```

The last two lines require user input.

Can someone let me know how can I automate the above using Python 2.7 which requires no user input?

Comment: So, you are trying to remove the safety from a gun?

Comment: yes. I don't need this for my use case.